# connecting sql server 16 to netbeans and pojo

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, netbeans, pojo

I built a project and created a database named freestyle in sql server 16 and then I wanted to connect to my database and use it in my project. Hibernate and reverse worked and I created them but when I wanted to move on to pojo level. It worked but nothing was created. I mean it was supposed to create some java class of my tables which did not work.

Comment: Did you remember to flip the "foo" box and flip the "bar" switch? How do you expect us to know that you did wrong, when you don't tell us what you did?

Comment: you can put some code and give more explanation about the steps that you did

Comment: Otherwise you can take a look at this youtube video may help you : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShFGdLTBuXo